# Azure Devops Pipelines with clean Python environment

Tags: python, azure-devops

I have an Azure Devops CI build set up to run a set of tests on my Python codebase. The pipeline runs using a local PC sitting on my desk, which I have added to the build pool. I installed Python 3.6 in the `_work\_tool` folder of the build agent and I start my pipelines .yaml files with a task:

```
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.6'
```

which grabs Python 3.6 and uses it for all "python" commands in subsequent steps.

This all works fine, but in order to run my tests, the packages in my python repo have to be installed on the python environment. I do this by calling a custom script that manually installs the packages one by one (essentially calls `python setup.py install` on each, which pulls in external dependencies as well). The problem is that I'm not convinced this installs the packages to a clean environment each time and so the python installation can end up using packages from previous build jobs.

Is there a way to ensure that each time a pipeline runs, the build agent uses a completely clean Python virtual environment for it?

Comment: use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` then `pip install -r requirements.txt` ?

Comment: The installation process isn't so much the problem as much as cleaning out the Python environment (removing references to packages from different builds) first. For now, my workaround is to explicitly create a new virtual environment for each build: `python -m venv pipeline_env` and then use this new python to install the packages contained in the source code with: `pipeline_env\Scripts\python.exe setup.py install` on each package I want to build and test. These leaves a virtual environment in agent file system for each build completed. Feels as though there must be a cleaner way.

Comment: @JitterRobin Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

In yaml, when you run a pipeline on a self-hosted agent, by default, none of the sub-directories are cleaned in between two consecutive runs. As a result, you can do incremental builds and deployments, provided that tasks are implemented to make use of that. You can override this behavior using the `workspace` setting on the job. Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#workspace) for details.

```
- job: myJob
  workspace:
    clean: outputs | resources | all # what to clean up before the job runs
```

- `outputs`: Delete `Build.BinariesDirectory` before running a new job.
- `resources`: Delete `Build.SourcesDirectory` before running a new job.
- `all`: Delete the entire `Pipeline.Workspace` directory before running a
  new job.

Note : `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` and `$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)` are always deleted and recreated prior to every build regardless of any of these settings.

As you said in the question:"I do this by calling a custom script that manually installs the packages one by one". If your packages are not installed in the workspace directory, the `clean` option cannot delete these packages.

[image]

So, as a workaround, you can empty the folder where the package is installed via cmd or script. For example:

```
rmdir /s/q path\folderName
mkdir path\folderName
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do any of these options clean out the package library for the Python environment used by the build? I already have the clean 'all' option set (in yaml), but that doesn't seem to help unfortunately.

Comment: If your packages are not installed in the workspace directory, the clean option cannot delete these packages.So as a workaround, you can empty the local folder where the package is installed via cmd or script.Please view my update.

Comment: Thanks @Hugh Lin The python pacakages are just being installed to the default site_packagea for the interpreter which is why they are ending up in the _tool folder. My workaround with the virtual environment means the packages are then in the working directory and can be cleaned in the way you say. I guess in my opinion the default for pipelines using python as a tool should be always to make a new python virtual environment for each build for me, guaranteeing a clean pipeline. I think this is the most common use case/expected behaviour, but perhaps others would disagree.