# Python Code to run Azure Devops Pipelines

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-python-sdk

The below solution is to trigger a pipeline by providing a pipeline ID explicitly in code. But If we have 5 pipelines created and if we run python code it should run the all pipeline that we created and important thing here is, Once we run python code it should fetch the pipeline Id dynamically and then it should run every pipeline.

I felt for this we need to create a function in python : Here is the reference link that i am sharing.

[Azure python blob storage trigger run azure devops pipeline problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/314263/azure-python-blob-storage-trigger-run-azure-devops.html)

Hope it may helps to get some idea to achive this task.

Can Any one please help me to achive this task.

Comment: You can refer to [azure-pipelines-python](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-pipelines-python) and [Azure Devops Pipelines with clean Python environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60636285/azure-devops-pipelines-with-clean-python-environment)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.